# html charset that works with Japanese and English characters?

Tags: html, character-encoding

This is the first time I experienced this problem. For some reason when I use this

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

my dashes are replaced with â€, but japanese characters work fine. I remember using another charset and the situation was flipped (Japanese characters were replaced with nonsense characters)

Is there a general charset that fits all? I'm completely new to this idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using UTF-8. Note that just changing the charset in the header won't convert the content — you need to make sure that the content is actually UTF-8 as well.

Comment: so you're saying I should have...  
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> ? 
hm.. my dashes still are replaced by that  â€...

Comment: @Oliver: No; you should use this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`. You should then make sure that your content is UTF-8 encoded.