# PHP(link MySQL) Japanese echo string becomes question marks

Tags: php, sql

I am sure I have already set character code to utf-8 but all Japanese characters still become ? when I open it on the html. Please help to solve.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>社員資料削除(Delete members' info</title>
</head>
<body >

<?php
$select_id=$_GET["id"];

$dbcon = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$result = mysql_select_db('isl_member', $dbcon);
$query_sn= mysql_query("Select Surname from member WHERE Member_id= '$select_id'",$dbcon);
$query_fn= mysql_query("Select First_name from member WHERE Member_id= '$select_id'",$dbcon);
$query_age= mysql_query("Select Age from member WHERE Member_id= '$select_id'",$dbcon);
$query_sex= mysql_query("Select Sex from member WHERE Member_id= '$select_id'",$dbcon);
$query_dep= mysql_query("Select Department from member WHERE Member_id= '$select_id'",$dbcon);
$result = mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8', $dbcon);
if (!$result) {
  exit('文字コードを指定できませんでした。');
}
mb_language("uni");
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8"); //内部文字コードを変更
mb_http_input("auto");
mb_http_output("utf-8");
?>

社員資料削除

<form method="post" action="index2.php?id=<?php echo $select_id ?>">
社員番号(worker id):<?php echo $select_id ?></br>
苗字(Surname):
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_sn, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo($row["Surname"]);}
mysql_free_result($query_sn)?> </br>
名前(First name):
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_fn, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo($row["First_name"]); }
mysql_free_result($query_fn)?></br>
性別(Sex):
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_sex, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo($row["Sex"]);}
mysql_free_result($query_sex)?></br>
年齢(Age):
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_age, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo($row["Age"]);}
mysql_free_result($query_age)?></br>
部署(Department):
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_dep, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo($row["Department"]);}
mysql_free_result($query_dep)?></br>

<input type="submit" value="削除(Delete)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to link this with my SQL Database. 
Currently 社員番号(worker id) and 年齢(ages) are available to show. Others all become ??????. If I change those items to English, then become available to view without problem. Therefore I am sure there are so trouble with character code. English explanations are added on the website, code on editor is without English explanation.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782669/html-charset-that-works-with-japanese-and-english-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782669/html-charset-that-works-with-japanese-and-english-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default encoding for inbound connections isn't set properly. `DEFAULT CHARSET` will return as `utf8` however `character_set_server` will be something different. Your `character_set_server` may set as `latin1`.

**Solution**

Set `default-character-set=utf8`

More Info : https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-database-character-encoding-177698.html

Comment: My SQL data are all set up with utf8. Just few minutes before, I added ''header('Content-type: text; charset=UTF-8'); '' in to my code and delete "$result = mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8', $dbcon);
if (!$result) {
  exit('文字コードを指定できませんでした。');
}
mb_language("uni");
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8"); //内部文字コードを変更
mb_http_input("auto");
mb_http_output("utf-8");" It does work but I dont understand why ...

Comment: it works with header('Content-type: text; charset=UTF-8'); Can you help to explain why it works with this code? Thank you very for your kind help.

Comment: By `header` function. PHP is returning the `content-charset` to the browser. It means, PHP says to browser `Hey, The response charset is UTF-8` Then browser will show it correctly. Because there are many charsets available , So we should specify... thats it

Comment: but why we dont need to set up  header('Content-type: text; charset=UTF-8'); in the other programme? I live in Japan now so normally the code I need to write are all in utf-8. Normally if set the editor and SQL to utf-8 then it will work. What is the difference here? Sorry for keep asking ...

Comment: Browser may support UTF-8 by default. But Still MySQL's default charset is `Latin1` and also your text editor's default charset is deferment. So they can't communicate each other. that's why you needed to change text-editor & mySQL charset